# angular ui-router state how is controller being called

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have see people post things online about using Angular ui-router and i see these types are code that do not explicitly even show an controller name, so how is it even suppose to know how to call the controller?

```
state('new-rp', {
  url: '/new/:portfolioId',
  templateUrl: 'new.html',
  controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.portfolioId = $stateParams.portfolioId;
  }
})
```

Code of mine that I TRIED that does NOT list the controller like above

```
.state("deviceDetail", {
        url: "/devices/:DeviceId",  // param is required which specific device id
        templateUrl: "app/devices/deviceDetailView.html",  // ui elements 
        controller: function($scope,$stateParams) {
            $scope.DeviceId = $stateParams.DeviceId;
        }

    });
```

Problem is the controller is NOT hit

But this code explicitly uses the controller name and the controller gets hit,  thus i'm having trouble with how   this type of code would hit a controller

```
controller: function($scope,$stateParams) {
            $scope.DeviceId = $stateParams.DeviceId;
        }
```

**HOW does it know?**     (doesn't work for me )

Comment: The examples you are showing are of an *inline* Controller function;  These aren't calling an external Controller, they are creating a Controller of that function body on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare controllers in two ways in UI router states:

```
//1
.state('new-rp', {
  url: '/new/:portfolioId',
  templateUrl: 'new.html',
  controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.portfolioId = $stateParams.portfolioId;
  }
})

//2
 .state('new-rp', {
  url: '/new/:portfolioId',
  templateUrl: 'new.html',
  controller: PortfolioController
})
.
.
.
//PortfolioController definition
```

In method #1, your controller is created for you inline, while in #2, UI Router is looking for an explicitly declared controller called `PortfolioController`

Comment: Ok,  I'm not understanding the purpose of inline controller,  I suppose it is for someone who doesn't need much code ?   Can you specify 2 controllers ?  How about call a Function or Service?   thx

Comment: You're right. If you just have a little controller code, and don't want to modularise and split out the code into separate controllers, you can use inline controllers. You can call a Service like from within any controller, and for that matter do whatever you can do in a normal controller (Except maybe re-use this controller elsewhere, as this is essentially an anonymous function). I doubt if you can specify two controllers. That would create ambiguity

Comment: Gracias Dustin , appreciate it